# Convert all Google Docs/Sheets/Slides to Microsoft Office?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, google-slides, google-takeout

I want to move away from Google, but before that, I would like to backup my documents in my GDrive. I unfortunately have a lot of Google Docs/Slides/Sheets, which won't be usable anymore if I stop using Google. Is there a way to convert them all into Microsoft Office Doc/Powerpoint/Excel files?

If I open them individually, I can save them as docx/pptx/xlsx, But I'm looking for an automated solution for all of my files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Google Takeout

Follow the instructions in the official Google Takeout help article: [Download your data](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190?hl=en)

1. Select data to include in your archive
2. Customize your archive format
3. Get your archive

On the help article each step has detailed instructions and notes.

#### Issues

- Limited specificity: Can only select folders from the root level of Google Drive files
- Shared files: The export only contain files you
  created not files shared with you.

#### Shared files workaround

- Download the folder manually
- Make copies of shared files before the export.