# How to export all my org's documents from Google Drive/Google Docs to OpenDocument?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

My organisation is using Google Workspace (formerly G Suite), mostly Google Docs and Google Drive, to host a mix of documents in various formats. As an admin, how do I export all the documents (or all the documents in one shared folder) to an archive file containing them in OpenDocument format?

For various reasons, we can't rely on this any more and we want a backup copy of all the documents (for instance, both Google Slides and PPTX) in OpenDocument format (ODT, ODS, ODP etc.). I'm particularly interested in converting Google Documents to OpenDocument formats rather than Microsoft formats. I'm happy with the usual OpenDocument output of the various Google Docs download options like Google Sheets' [Print and download files](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9306091).

I've read [How to download your Google data](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190) (about Google Takeout) and [Export your organization's data](https://support.google.com/a/answer/100458) (about the Data Export tool) and [I respect the limits](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/143086/export-all-users-data-from-google-drive) but there's no mention of an OpenDocument format option. Takeout seems to hardcode Microsoft formats and I've not seen an option to use anything else in the Data export tool.

I see there are various scripts and libraries like ["aiogoogle" Async Google API client](https://pypi.org/project/aiogoogle/), but I didn't find one which explicitly supports this use case already.

Comment: This is different from https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/141715/convert-all-google-docs-sheets-slides-to-microsoft-office because I already know how to export to Microsoft formats, but that's not enough.